# Java Eclipse: unexpected change to Build Path

Tags: java, eclipse

For our project, we had to upgrade our Spring jar files. We downloaded these files and placed them at our JarRepository. We then manually modified the **build.xml** as follows:

**before**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    ...
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/JarRepository/lib/spring-tx-2.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/JarRepository/lib/spring-web-2.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/JarRepository/lib/spring-webmvc-2.5.jar"/>
    ...
</classpath>
```

**after**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    ...
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/JarRepository/lib/spring-tx-2.5.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/JarRepository/lib/spring-web-2.5.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/JarRepository/lib/spring-webmvc-2.5.6.jar"/>
    ...
</classpath>
```

As far as I'm aware, I've ONLY changed the "2.5.jar" into --> "2.5.6.jar"

But unfortunately in Eclipse, (as found in Build Path >> Libraries) it changed as follows:

**before**

```
...
spring-tx-2.5.jar - JarRepository/lib
spring-web-2.5.jar - JarRepository/lib
spring-webmvc-2.5.jar - JarRepository/lib
...
```

**after**

```
...
spring-tx-2.5.6.jar - \JarRepository\lib (missing)
spring-web-2.5.6.jar - \JarRepository\lib (missing)
spring-webmvc-2.5.6.jar - \JarRepository\lib (missing)
...
```

It was observed that the slashes have reversed. This may have caused it to be "missing" status.

Please help. This has caused us compile errors.

- I've tried closing and opening Eclipse (as stated by other build path
  error questions).
- I'm using latest Eclipse Oxygen
- (as suggested by @André Stannek)I tried using Eclipse menu (Add external jars). It may fix the problem but it would now use the Absolute path. It would be best if we use Relative path.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Have you tried editing the build path using the mentioned Eclipse menu? I'd try to delete the libraries there and re-add it. It wouldn't explain the cause of your problem but it at least might solve it.

Comment: @AndréStannek Thanks for the idea. Using the Eclipse menu would surely fix this. But it would now use its absolute path. Since our code will be sent to a different host, it would be best to stick to its relative path (as we observed from other classpath entries)

Answer (score 0):

Its now fixed. Although I don't know which SPECIFIC one have solved my problem; but I have tried to do the following in this order:

1. (In Eclipse menu bar) Project >> Clean... >> Clean All Projects
2. Closed and Re-opened Eclipse
3. Delete All Projects in Eclipse (NOT permanent delete)
4. Re-import project into Eclipse
5. (In Eclipse menu bar) Project >> Clean... >> Clean All Projects
6. Re-build

The paths to the newly upgraded Spring files are now fixed, and in Relative path form.

Still don't know the cause of the problem though. But anyways.